# InApp subscription purchased with Alpha apk is not showing in google wallet

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

In the Google Play console I created an inapp Subscription product, and managed to get my android app to purchase the subscription. As the app is at the Alpha stage in google play, google forces the sub to be daily recurring with no actual charge to the test user.
So far so good.
However I'd like to cancel the test subscription....according to google documentation I can do so in google wallet but it's not showing in the test user's google wallet account. So how do I cancel this subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going here:

https://play.google.com/store/account

You'll see all your active subscriptions

Comment: Yes, logging in as the test user then looking in their google play account pages did the trick